# Load Reddit buttons dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

How can I reload Reddit buttons with jquery? I have load more ajax function and Reddit buttons don't appear when loaded via jquery. I tried to use:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button2.js', dataType: 'script', 
cache:true});
```

This is the actual button attached to each post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
reddit_url = "http://domain.com/post-num";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button2.js">
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by updating the Reddit **iframe's** "src".

```
$('some-surrounding-div-here').find('iframe').attr('src','http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button2.html?width=51&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fpost-num');
```

Here it is in a full working example:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
         $(function(){
             $('#refresh_reddit_button').click(function(){
                   $('#reddit_button_container').find('iframe').attr('src','http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button2.html?width=51&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fpost-num');
             });
         });
    </script>            
</head>

<body>
     <input id="refresh_reddit_button" type="button" value="Refresh Reddit">
     <div id="reddit_button_container">        
           <script type="text/javascript">
                  reddit_url = "http://domain.com/post-num";
           </script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/static/button/button2.js">
           </script> 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try the whole code sample? When you click the "Refresh Reddit" you can see the reddit button below refreshes (for example, I actually see the text 'submit' animate again). However, maybe you need it to do something more, like bring in different reddit content or something??

Comment: although it selects and changes the link of the reddit button, it doesn't work for buttons loaded by POST method

Comment: i discovered that when loading the buttons through POST, iframe of the button will not be created so changing the SRC won't work because the buttons isn't there at all